# Event Bar only on End Data Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

Hello guys I am using fullcalendar for my calendar. right now if I create a event it shows a bar from the starting date to the target date. But this kind of view is not ok for me. I just want the that bar to come on the start and finish date not in between.

Like if the a event is starting 15 Feb to 25 Feb. If I use the default fullcalendar view it will show a long bar starting from 15 and going upto 25th covering the dates that come in between them. But I just want that bar to come on 25th not 15th or 16th or 17th ... 23rd or 24th.

I can't figure out how to do this. Can somebody tell me how can I do thi.

Here is my code through which I'm populating my calendar with events:

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        viewRender: function (view) {

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url +"apps/calendar/getByMonth",
                async : false,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {'type': $('#formName').val() },
                success: function(mark_up){

                  mark_up = JSON.parse(mark_up);
                  my_events = mark_up["task"];
                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
                       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', my_events);
                }
            });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. You will need to register two separate events or just one event on the end date.

Take a look at this
[Display only event's start date and end date in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564890/display-only-events-start-date-and-end-date-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: If I do like this there are two problems that I'll get. I will not be able to know what is the starting or ending date. and then another problem that I'll face is that when I click on a event at that moment I'm retrieving all the data from the event and showing in modal. If I follow this approach then the start and end date that I'll get will be same

Comment: What you can do is create your custom function to handle event click. And store all the data for an event in some variable. You can play around. Don't use only fullcalendar to store your events data.